# How to use wget on Windows just to access an URL WITHOUT download any page

Tags: windows, command-line, wget

How to use wget on Windows just to access an URL WITHOUT download any page ? I just want to send a HTTP REQUEST . ( It will dispare a function on cakephp )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to issue wget as follows:

```
wget http://example.com/controller/action/param -O NUL
```

This is valid for GET requests.

Comment: Thank you @Inigo Flores ! Works like a charm.